# Translate(Slide in) animation not working android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app what i want is that on button click i wanna slide in a fragment and on again on click slide out the fragment.My code for sliding the fragment down is working but the sliding in transition is not working..

Slide Up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="getXFraction"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1000"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

Slide down

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1280"
        android:duration="1000"/>
```

Code

```
private void toggleList() {
        Fragment f = getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (f != null) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_up,
                            R.animator.slide_down,
                            R.animator.slide_up,
                            R.animator.slide_down)
                    .add(R.id.frag_container, new frag(),
                            LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG
                    ).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hardcoding the translation values doesn't seem a good idea. Personally, I'd the animations programmatically, so you can assign them appropriate to screen size.

Comment: why do you have two ObjectAnimator in your SlideUp ?

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON please can you guide me how to do that??

Comment: @MurtazaHussain sir that one is for alpha

Comment: try to remove the alpha one and check again.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `xFraction` (in my code, it's just `xFraction` not `getXFraction`), I believe you only need to animate between 0 and 1 (the unit is screen width). Setting the latter to 100 results in moving object 100x the screen width. `Slide down` is working (but only for a specific screen size) because in that case you are using `yTranslate`, for which the units are pixels. In that case, you'd be better to use `yFraction` set from 0 to 1. As others have commented, if all else fails, test `slide in` as a solo animation before adding it to a set.